# Setting culture info dynamically

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am building an application in asp.net/c#. For dates in my application, I amm using global variables which give date formats from a given database.

So if my `DateFormat` is British I use:

```
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("en-GB");
```

if it is US I use:

```
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("en-US");
```

So my dates are validated and compared using this approach. My question is; should I just check for the format only once for the entire application or will I have to check the formats for every page as I know that for every new thread `CultureInfo` gets reset?

Could you please suggest the the correct way of doing this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This need to be done for each request. You can write a HttpModule that will set current thread culture for each request.

** Each request is a new thread

EDIT: Example added.

Lets create a HttpModule as follows and set the culture.

```
public class CultureModule:IHttpModule
{
    public void Dispose()
    {          
    }
    public void Init(HttpApplication context)
    {
        context.PostAuthenticateRequest += new EventHandler(context_PostAuthenticateRequest);           
    }
    void context_PostAuthenticateRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var requestUri = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri;
        /// Your logic to get the culture.
        /// I am reading from uri for a region
        CultureInfo currentCulture;
        if (requestUri.Contains("cs"))
            currentCulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("cs-CZ");
        else if (requestUri.Contains("fr"))
            currentCulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("fr-FR");
        else
            currentCulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US");

        System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = currentCulture;
    }

}
```

Register the Module in web.config,(Under system.web for classic mode and under system.webserver for integrated mode.

```
<system.web>
......
<httpModules>
  <add name="CultureModule" type="MvcApplication2.HttpModules.CultureModule,MvcApplication2"/>
</httpModules>
</system.web>
<system.webServer>
.....
<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
  <add name="CultureModule" type="MvcApplication2.HttpModules.CultureModule,MvcApplication2"/>
</modules>
```

Now if we browser the url like,(assuming default route in MVC point to Home/index and port 78922)

1. http://localhost:78922/Home/Index  -  Culture will be "en-US"
2. http://localhost:78922/Home/Index/cs  -  Culture will be "cs-CZ"
3. http://localhost:78922/Home/Index/fr  -  Culture will be "fr-FR"

*** **JUST AN EXAMPLE, USE YOUR LOGIC TO SET CULTURE**...

Comment: thanks ,,, could you please assist me with an example if possible..... and by doing as you mentioned , i dont need to write it again right ??thanks

Comment: ,,,, thanks a lot ,,, it helped ,,,, another doubt i have is whether i should include this in a seperate .cs file ,, is it ??? thanks

Comment: Yes, its better to keep one class per cs file

Comment: i just kept that in a .cs file and set the configuration in web.config ,, but the dates i am trying to compare are not giving correct results , i am using compare validator for that.any idea what may be missing

Comment: Are you trying to compare dates based on cultureIfno ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to set it just once for the session

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/306162